# TypeError: string or bytes-like object expected

Tags: python

I am trying to tokenize tweet but I get the error:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I am cleaning tweets for use in ml, so am carryout tokenization.

```
# remove twitter handles (@user)
def remove_pattern(input_txt, pattern):
    r = re.findall(pattern, input_txt)
    for i in r:
        input_txt = re.sub(i, '', input_txt)

    return input_txt  

# remove twitter handles and create new column with clean tweet
data_df['cleaned_tweet'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(data_df['text'], "@[\w]*")
```

Comment: Please include the *exact* error message.

Comment: Also include more code, to see what types are in Input of your code

Answer (score 4):

This is because the twitter text is not a string, it is an object, you have to convert object into string, write: `input_txt =str(input_txt)`.